# Advice on grease pencil capabilities

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm new to digital art/blender and I'm just getting started learning everything and I could use some advice. I have been somewhat struggling with grease pencil lately trying to get it to do what I want it to, its making me wonder if what I'm trying to do isn't within the scope of the grease pencil tool. That being said, let me tell you my goal/what I'm trying to do and hopefully you all can let me know if its possible or not.

So my end goal would be to do digital painting and concept art with shading and color contrast and to possibly use that in some sort of animation.

I've been trying to do it all in blender cause its a one stop shop for everything and I'm enjoying it so far. But what I'm finding is that since the grease pencil is vector based, I'm having trouble achieving the finer details, like blending colors together and shading, having special brushes, etc... I'm taking that this finer level of detail is achievable but with pixel based approach (photoshop/Krita). Is what I'm trying to do really only viable for the pixel based approach or can it be done with vector based?

Comment: This seems to be possible with grease pencil based on the artwork people have created with it, e.g. https://twitter.com/tonroosendaal/status/1555503573903048704

Answer (score 0):

I feel your fustration. Try [Affinity Designer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_Designer). I draw my images freehand, scan them, then run them through the path-trace in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) to trace my drawings to vector, and then I color them in Affinity Designer. I make sure to use the selection tool so I can shade and do stuff. As far as Blender there is a free brush pack I think! Blender for me is great for the animation and the video editor for setting up scenes to help out
with persepective. I also use the freestyle setting to quickly get a comic book scene that I can color in. Then use it as a background image. My advice is to use
a lot of tools.